# How to load percentage of data with sklearn.datasets.load_files

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, deep-learning, keras

I have 8000 images which I am loading with [sklearn.datasets.load_files](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html) and passing through resnet from [keras](https://keras.io/applications/#resnet50) to get bottleneck features. However this task is taking hours on a GPU so I'd like to find out if there is a way to tell `load_files` to load a percentage of data like 20%.

I'm doing this to train my own top layer (last dense layer) and attach it to resnet.

```
def load_dataset(path):
    data = load_files(path)
    files = np.array(data['filenames'])
    targets = np_utils.to_categorical(np.array(data['target']), 100)
    return files, targets

train_files, train_targets = load_dataset('images/train')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like it would be better suited for the Keras `ImageDataGenerator` class and to use the `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory` method. You don't have to use data augmentation with it (which would slow it down further) but you can choose your batch size to pull from the directory instead of loading them all.

Copied from https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/ and slightly modified with notes.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(  # <- customize your transformations
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,  # <- control how many images are loaded each batch
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,  # <- reduce here to lower the overall images used
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

**Edit**

Per your question below...
steps_per_epoch determines how many batches are loaded for each epoch.

For example:

- steps_per_epoch = 50
- batch_size = 32
- epochs = 1

Would give you 1,600 images total for that epoch. Which is exactly 20% of your 8,000 images. **Note** that if you run into memory problems with a batch size of 32, you may want to decrease this and increase your steps_per_epoch. It will take some tinkering with to get it right.

Comment: Can you explain how steps per epoch is the same as the number of images

Comment: It allows you to control the total number of images, I just edited my post with more details on how you might want to use it.

Comment: In the end I will trim the data by hand. I use a generator on the trimmed data - the reason I asked my question is bc I'm not sure if the generator chooses at random from all classes (Which I'd prefer) or not. My hunch is that it goes in order.

Comment: You can set the shuffle parameter to True and it will choose randomly.