# How many images are generated using Keras ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

> ***How many*** image transformations are done **for each single image**?

I read a couple of posts and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783945/how-to-load-percentage-of-data-with-sklearn-datasets-load-files/49784152?noredirect=1#comment86584555_49784152) is close.
But it does not answer my question clearly: Suppose I have the same `steps_per_epoch = 50`, `batch size = 32` and `sample size = 100`.

If I use image augmentation with `ImageDataGenerator` with (`shuffle = on`), is that still going to generate 1600 images for training?
But if I have 5000 training images, how will it work? Will it still generate new images or use original images?

Answer (score 1):

The original images are just transformed (i.e. rotation, zooming, etc.) every epoch and then used for training, and the number of images in each epoch is equal to the number of original images you have.

By doing this you're creating new data.
This way the learned model may be more robust and accurate

Comment: `The original images are just transformed...`

But, how many times? *How many* transformations for each image?

Comment: ImageDataGenerator is a batches Generator of tensor image data with real-time data augmentation. The data will be looped over (in batches). This means that will on the fly apply transformations to batch of images randomly.At every new epoch new random transformations will be applied and in this way we train with a little different set of images each time.